# AWSCognitoIdentityProvider.adminCreateUser(...) failed to satisfy constraint: Member must not be null

Tags: java, eclipse, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am using Eclipse for Java with AWS Toolkit. I run this code:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        AmazonCognitoIdentityClient client = new AmazonCognitoIdentityClient();

        client.trial();
        
        UserType userType = client.signUp();
        
    }

}

public class AmazonCognitoIdentityClient {
    
    public void trial() {
        
        AWSCognitoIdentityProvider cognitoClient = getAmazonCognitoIdentityClient();
        System.out.println(userPoolType.getSchemaAttributes());
        
    }

    public AWSCognitoIdentityProvider getAmazonCognitoIdentityClient() {
        ClasspathPropertiesFileCredentialsProvider propertiesFileCredentialsProvider = 
                new ClasspathPropertiesFileCredentialsProvider();

        return AWSCognitoIdentityProviderClientBuilder.standard()
                .withCredentials(propertiesFileCredentialsProvider)
                .withRegion("us-east-1")
                .build();

    }
    
    public UserType signUp() {

        AWSCognitoIdentityProvider cognitoClient = getAmazonCognitoIdentityClient();
        AdminCreateUserRequest cognitoRequest = new AdminCreateUserRequest()
                .withUserPoolId("us-east-1_PJa8U1lw3")
                .withUsername("yahoo")
                .withUserAttributes(
                        new AttributeType()
                        .withValue("dbrower256@yahoo.com"),
                        new AttributeType()
                        .withName("sub")
                        .withValue("sub"),
                        new AttributeType()
                        .withName("name")
                        .withValue("Daniel"),
                        new AttributeType()
                        .withName("given_name")
                        .withValue("Daniel"),
                        new AttributeType()
                        .withName("family_name")
                        .withValue("Brower"),
                        new AttributeType()
                        .withName("phone_number")
                        .withValue("9032761046"),
                        new AttributeType()
                        .withName("email_verified")
                        .withValue("true"))
                .withTemporaryPassword("TEMPORARY_PASSWORD")
                .withMessageAction("SUPPRESS")
                .withDesiredDeliveryMediums(DeliveryMediumType.EMAIL)
                .withForceAliasCreation(Boolean.FALSE);

        AdminCreateUserResult createUserResult = cognitoClient.adminCreateUser(cognitoRequest);
        UserType cognitoUser = createUserResult.getUser();

        return cognitoUser;

    }

}
```

I get this in Console View:

> [ ... {Name: name,AttributeDataType: String,DeveloperOnlyAttribute: false,Mutable: true,Required: false,StringAttributeConstraints: {MinLength: 0,MaxLength: 2048}} ... ]
>
> Exception in thread "main" com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidp.model.InvalidParameterException: 1 validation error detected: Value null at 'userAttributes.1.member.name' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must not be null ...

As you can see from the print of getSchemaAttributes(), "name" is not required. Why am I getting an error saying that it cannot be null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to change this code:

```
                .withUserAttributes(
                        new AttributeType()
                        .withValue("dbrower256@yahoo.com"),
```

To something like:

```
                .withUserAttributes(
                        new AttributeType()
                        .withName(...)
                        .withValue("dbrower256@yahoo.com"),
```